# Blackberry Class Cast Exception

Tags: blackberry, java-me, classcastexception

I'm having a class cast exception in my code.
I'm using Richlist in it on adding Label Field it is giving me a class cast exception.
How to resolve this issue?

```
RichList list = new RichList(vfm, true,2, 1); 
list.add(new Object[]  {
    new BitmapField((arrow),Field.FIELD_RIGHT), 
    new LabelField(ModelController.getInstance().getJsonArrayGroup().getJSONObject(counter).getString("name")){
        protected void paint(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(0x0511a0a); 
            super.paint(g);
        }
    },
    "",  
    new SeparatorField()});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the RichList example documentation on blackberry.com](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Rich_list_1228594_11.jsp).

Even though the API for the `add()` method takes an array of `Object`, in practice, it expects you to pass it `Bitmap` and `String` objects.

Maybe something like this, for you:

```java
list.add(new Object[] { arrow, 
                        ModelController.getInstance().getJsonArrayGroup().getJSONObject(counter).getString("name"),
                        "" });
```

Comment: Yes I have read, but how can I then change a color of a text?

Comment: Not sure.  That's a different question.  Your ClassCastException, however, is because you're trying to add a LabelField, and not a String.

Comment: Yeah.. Alright I will accept your answer now. But I really need to know how can I change color of a text in a richlist. If you could tell I will appreciate.

Comment: You should just post a new question, basically asking how to customize font colors, and still use a `RichList`.  It's hard for people to search through questions if the topic changes.  I don't actually know how to do what you want to do, but if I have some time tomorrow (and you post a new question), I'll look into it.  Thanks.